# I keep on getting one error regarding connectNode method

Tags: java

I have a node class defined as below, but I keep on getting the error in Eclipse

> void is an invalid type for the variable connectNode

Please explain why?

```
 class Node{

    char label;

    boolean visited = false;

    public Node (char l){
        this.label=l;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return Character.toString(label);
    }
 }
```

I have defined ArrayList as below:

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

I'm trying to use the following method to print the values of Start and End index

```
public void connectNode(Node start,Node end){
   int startIndex=nodes.indexOf(start);
   int endIndex=nodes.indexOf(end);

   System.out.println(startIndex);
   System.out.println(endIndex);

}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get this exception?

Comment: Can you add the full file connectNode is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error usually arises when you try to declare a method inside another method.
Recheck your code and file structure.

Comment: You are right. I"m defining it in another method. I'll declare each class in different file. Thanks !

Comment: Upvote require 15 reputation and therefore I'm unable to upvote your post however I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're doing something like:

```
nodes.add(connectNode(start, end));
```

If that's the case then it means you're trying to insert something that is not suitable for this array list. More specifically you try to put void in a list of type Node.

Comment: I'm trying to print the start and end index of the ArrayList. I have already entered A,B,C,D,E,F characters in the arraylist using the nodes object. I'm wondering what's wrong with the method?

Comment: You still didn't write what is the flow you're running and where exactly this exception happens.